# How to preserve the values ordering of a sorted map?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I have a sorted map and would like to retrieve the values in the order of their corresponding keys.  I.e. if my sorted map has (1,6), (2,4), (3,1), I want to retrieve [6,4,1].

Is there something faster than iterating over the sorted map like so?

```
SortedMap<Double, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Double, Double>(sortedMap.size());
List<Double> values = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (Entry<Double, Double> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
    values.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

I don't think simply doing:

```
values = new ArrayList<Double>(sortedMap.values())
```

would work since sortedMap.values() returns a Collection with no guarantees on the order but iterating over the map doesn't strike me as efficient.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#values() 
>  The collection's iterator returns the values in ascending order of the corresponding keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sortedMap.values() returns a Collection with no guarantees on the order

According to docs for SortedMap the order is guaranteed, see:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#values()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#values%28%29)

Comment: "The collection's iterator returns the values in ascending order of the corresponding keys."

Comment: This is great. Just hovering over .values() in Eclipse showed me the javadoc for Map, not for SortedMap, which is why I didn't see the part about the ordering.  I will remember to go the actual doc next time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think iterating over a sorted map is slow? In order to retrieve all the values you would have to eventually iterate through the entire Map. So the time complexity will always be O(n).

Comment: I assume(d) that if there was a library call available, it would probably be more optimized than iterating over the map manually. But that's a good question: I am not at all sure that is a good assumption.

Comment: the for-each loop is an optimal way of iterating through an collection. Moreover Language designers have put lots of effort in designing the iterators for Java collections to ensure that its the fastest way to loop through any collection. I think first you need to profile and see if the performance is really slow.